# Is it possible to create animated markers in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, pdf, animation

I remember reading somewhere last year that arcgis 10 would allow the creation of animated markers (alike animated .gifs) that could be either exported to pdfs or seen inside arcmap.

Does such feature actually exist?

Comment: Have you considered using WPF?  It is much friendlier for animation.  Richie Carmichael has an example here for WPF in arcmap: http://mrrichie.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!DD16C3F34F4D913E!2502.entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **Export** animated markers [.bmp.jpeg] with the "Exporting an animation as sequential images"

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00090000004t000000.htm

But to have animated markers inside ArcMap - No.
Though you could try loading in an animated gif as a map marker.